# Eclipse with ADK does not see listview.smoothScrollToPosition

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, intellisense

The intellisense does not show smoothScrollToPosition and when I put it in I get an error stating that "The method smoothScrollToPosition(int) is undefined for the type ListView".

Here is my implementation:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int index, long id) {
    debug("item "+index+" clicked");
    listView.smoothScrollToPosition(index);
}
```

I have API 8 and 16 installed via SDK Manager in Eclipse and I am targeting APIs 8-16.

In an attempt to work around this issue I created a method to manually scroll the list, but it didn't work either.  The numbers are all correct but the list only moves on the last iteration of i.

[updated function]

```
private void animateItem(View view, int targetY, int duration) throws Exception{

    int sleepTime = duration/10;
    int position = listView.getPositionForView(view);
    int viewTop = view.getTop();
    debug("animating item "+position+" from "+view.getTop()+" to "+targetY+" for "+duration+" millis");;
    for (int i=1; i<=10; i++){
        int y = (viewTop-targetY)/2;
        debug("... animation progress - top:"+viewTop+"   distance:"+(viewTop-targetY)+"     y:"+y);

        listView.setSelectionFromTop(position, y);
        viewTop -= y;
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for such refinement, but in your Project -> Preferences -> Android selected Android API 8 or higher?

Comment: DOH!  I changed it in my manifest file but when I checked the preferences it was still set to 7.  I cannot tell you how long I stressed over this :)  That did the trick so you can answer this. Thanks!

Comment: New to StackOverflow and I'm not sure how to make this question answered.  I think you need to click the answer button and re-enter your answer?  Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for such refinement, but in your Project -> Preferences -> Android selected Android API 8 or higher?